# Macro on sublime text 3

Tags: macros, sublimetext3

I want to create a macro in sublime text 3, to do:

Replace all beginnig of the line with '
Replace all beginnig of the end with ',

I recorded the macro doing this with cntl H and making the replaces, then save the macro but when I want to execute it don't do it.

Is there any other way to record macros for replaces?

Example:

Before:

```
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
12313
```

After:

```
'12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313', '12313'
```

Thanks
Regards

Comment: I've edited your question to include the example inside the question. You should not post an answer to simply include the example, so you can remove that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using this actions (which you can record and save in a macro):

1. Press **ctrl+a**: select all.
2. Press **ctrl+shift+l**: split selection into lines.
3. Press **home**: move every cursor to the beginning of each line.
4. Press **'**: add *'* char at the bbeginning of each line.
5. Press **end**: move cursor at the end of each line.
6. Press **'** and then **space** and then **,** and then **supr**.
7. Press **ctrl+end** to move at the end of the line.
8. Press **backspace** two times to delete the extra space and comma at the end of the line.

You can also probablly do it using regex and snippets but macros are also a good way.